# Pass parameters for my element using page object model and page factory

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, page-factory

have a problem, my element needs to receive parameters to be able to locate an element, as you can do it using:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//iframe[contains(@id,'" + VAR + "')]")]
public IWebElement iframe{ get; set; }
```

I need to pass a parameter, Example:

```
var alumnoPage = new CrearAlumnoPage();
PageFactory.InitElements(driver, alumnoPage);
alumnoPage .iframe(VAR);
```

I must have all the elements of the pages there, if it does not break the POM

Do you know any solution?, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this using the `PageFactory.InitElements` method, But you can create a separate method inside your class for this, something like:

```
public IWebElement GetIFrame(string id)
{
    return driver.FindElement(By.Id(id));
}
```

So you can call it like this later:

```
alumnoPage.GetIFrame("your-unique-id");
```

If you set up your class like this, you can also use `WebDriverWait` to get your iframe:

```
class CrearAlumnoPage
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private WebDriverWait wait;

    public CrearAlumnoPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        // WebDriverWait is in OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI
    }

    public IWebElement GetIFrame(string id)
    {
        return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementLocated(By.Id(id)));
    }
}
```